# Filter to execute before render but after controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have some logic in a base controller to pass information to the view to build something like a breadcrumb:

```
class ContextAwareController < ApplicationController

  after_filter :build_breadcrumb

  def build_breadcumb
    #...
  end
end
```

I want this build_breadcrumb method to run **after** the main controller logic, but **before** the view is rendered.

The above code runs too late, but a before_filter would be too early.

Can anybody suggest a way to accomplish this without explicitly calling build_breadcumb at the end of each of the actions in the child controllers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe rendering starts when render is called, and there's no default way to defer it.  Here's one thing you could do:

filters are applied in the same order declared.  So make a second after-filter that calls render with an array args stored in a class variable.  Then anywhere you would normally call render, set the variable.

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def render *args
    add_breadcrumbs
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: But this solution would slow down every render.

Comment: It would only slow down the renders made from a particular controller. It would be easy enough to move this to a different controller or "sub-controller" so that only the actions that need breadcrumbs use this version of `render`.

Comment: We can also use a Controller Concern to add this functionality selectively 
http://elegantbrew.tumblr.com/post/70990048275/controller-concerns-in-rails-4

Answer (score 3):

There are also some gems to achieve this. One of them is [rails3_before_render](https://github.com/shell/rails3_before_render).
It works similarly to filters, for example:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_render :ping, :except => [:destroy]

  def index; end
  def new; end
  def show; end
  def destroy; end                                                                          

  private
    def ping
      Rails.logger.info "Ping-Pong actions"
    end
end
```

(code snipped copied from gem documentation)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this filter is executed only if you call _render_ method, thus before_render should not be used to update data in database when there is a possibility of redirect.

Answer (score 2):

If we're overriding `render`, we're not really using the filter chain at all, so it might be simpler to determine which action we're in using the `@_action_name`.

```
StuffController < ApplicationController

  def my_filter
    # Do the stuff
  end

  def render(*args)
    my_filter if @_action_name == "show"
    super
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias_method_chain` like this

```
alias_method_chain :render, :before_render_action
```

this will create 2 methods `:render_with_before_render_action` and `:render_without_before_render_action`. If you call render, then `:render_with_before_render_action` will be called. You can override this method

```
def render_with_before_render_action(*options, &block)
<your code>
render_without_before_render_action(*options, &block)
end
```

If you don't want your code to be executed and you want to have default render then you should directly call the `:render_without_before_render_action`

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this to fake a before_render:

```
class StuffController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :my_filter, only: [:index, :show]

  def my_filter
    @my_filter = true
  end
  def _my_filter
    # Do the actual stuff here
  end
  def render(*args)
    _my_filter if @my_filter
    super
  end
end
```

Thanks to @joshua-muheim for the tip about using `render`